# Why does my 2 website pages with the identical nav bars display differently?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all I would like to explain that I am relatively new to all of this coding thing. I am self-taught and am still learning.

I am having an issue with my own portfolio website [My Site](http://callumwatson.io)

On this site I have just directly copied and pasted the nav bar coding (HTML,CSS) from index.html to the work.html. I am using dreamweaver as my development programme and everything is displayed great and I hosted the site last night.

Now the site is live I am having a lot of issues with the nav bar and the css. I have created a new css file for each page (about,work and CV) and then copied the code for the nav-bar and background etc. onto the next page and loaded in the same js code file for all the pages and the waypoints navbar display code.

However as you will see from my site the nav-bar is displayed differently on each page, waypoints is not working on the about page or cv and all the formatting is off.

As I type I am pulling my hair out with this one as when I view in dream-weavers website viewer the site looks great and is fully functional. Can anyone help me out ?

The work page is the only page displaying correctly at this point in time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Callum

Comment: please, provide code snippets, and share them via JSFiddle, so you can get the faster reply. Right now you provided only the first link, and there's no another. The quality of the question is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without spending too long looking at the source code, I did notice that on the home page you are using different CSS from the workpage.

On the home page you are calling

```
<link href="../DW Bootstrap Site/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/callum.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and on the work page you are calling

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/work.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Which will alter the display of the age depending on the contents of these CSS files. You need to ensure that the css of each page is consisten - try to keep all external CSS in the one file so that it is a uniform call for each page. The different content for each page is then used by calling the different selectors on each page (id's and classes etc). There may well be other things wrong - that's what I noticed straight away.

Comment: Hi Gavgrif, thanks for the reply. I have used separate css files and copied the nav-bar and header information across. I done it this way as this was the only elements of the css I wanted to be the same and the rest was effectively a new page. Any idea why they might be displaying differently if I have just copied it across pages?

Comment: No worries Cal, happy to help, you will need to ensure that all css that relates to the display on the nav elements are uniform - as SilviaGreen said - you are missing the bootstrap css so there the home page will not render the same as the others. Just include it in the head and see how it changes the page and then replicate the changes through the other pages.. Gavgrif

Answer (score 0):

In your home page bootstrap.css is not found:

```
<link href="../DW Bootstrap Site/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Check the path, this is the correct one: http://callumwatson.io/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: That appears to have worked for the bootstrap elements, really appreciate that. However the nav-bar issue is still not working, any ideas? The nav-bars are different on each page and on the about waypoints isnt working. I have used a separate css's for each page but as said copied over the nav-bar coding.

Comment: Little bit left to align etc but hopefully helps me find a job.